# Dynamically creating variable names in python?

Tags: python, pygame

For my first "big" project in python I am trying to make a [simon says](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ugQWX.png) game clone with pygame

The blink() method requires me to detect what color the instance is (self.color)
and change the color based on that.

So red to brightred, blue to brightblue etc. The problem is that my current code is very long and ugly, and I know that there must be a better way to do it.

Here is my ugly code :

```
    def blink(self):
    if self.color == red:
        self.color = brightred
    elif self.color == blue:
        self.color = brightblue
    elif self.color == green:
        self.color = brightgreen
```

the defined colors :

```
black = (0,0,0)
white = (255,255,255)
red = (150,0,0)
green = (0,150,0)
blue = (0,0,150)
yellow = (150,150,0)
brightred = (255,0,0)
brightgreen = (0,255,0)
brightblue = (0,0,255)
brightyellow = (255,255,0)
```

and finally the class containing the method :

```
class rec:

    def __init__(self,left,top,size,color):
        self.left = left
        self.top = top
        self.size = size
        self.color = color
        self.rect = pygame.Rect(self.left,self.top,self.size,self.size)
        pygame.draw.rect(d,self.color,self.rect)
        pygame.display.update()

    def blink(self):
        if self.color == red:
            self.color = brightred
        elif self.color == blue:
            self.color = brightblue
        elif self.color == green:
            self.color = brightgreen
        elif self.color == yellow:
            self.color = brightyellow
        pygame.draw.rect(d,self.color,self.rect)
        pygame.display.update() # Not finished
```

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand the question. What's the problem here? What is your goal?

Answer (score 0):

Could you use a 2-dimensional array for your colors where [0][0] is red and [0][1] is brightred. On blink, you can just switch the second dimension to get brightred.

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to show the bright color, you could multiply your color values by `255/150`, which requires no if statements, except for the case of black to white, if you care about that

```
def blink(self):
    self.color = map(lambda c: c*(255/150), self.color)
```

Answer (score 0):

You've got two options. In both you should start with moving the specific colours from separate variables into an array, or a dictionary. Once you do that, you can:

1. Switch between colours by selecting an alternative.

For example:

```
 self.colour_name = 'red'
 colour = COLOURS[self.colour_name][is_bright]
```

2. Instead of specifically define each colour, make a function that makes the colour brighter. If you care about the colour being correct, you could convert to a different scale, reduce the brightness and convert back to RGB. But if you care only about the bright/dark difference, you could go with.

For example:

```
def make_bright(colour):
    return tuple(x*2 for x in colour)

...

if is_bright:
    colour = make_bright(COLOURS[self.colour_name])
else:
    colour = COLOURS[self.colour_name]
```